# Magento deleted items and addresses shown on new invoice?

Tags: php, magento, magmi

I used Magmi to import and delete items, and today a customer made a purchase of one single item and guess what :

His name was changed to Peter Hoang(the default magento customer name), also the address was changed and another 4 items were added to customer's invoice (items that I deleted few weeks ago).

Items and adresses are mixed up at every order.

I reindexed, refreshed cache, cleaned var/cache and sessions but nothing, its happening at every order...any ideas of how should I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you changed your customer's **First name** only in `Account Information` section only. You need to change in Address section also.In your admin panel go to `Customers --> Manage Customesr --> Select your customer --> Address (left side bar)`. Here you can see the address of your customer is not changed. Change it, then save..Thats it..Cheers ..!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Elavarasan, but I never modified that. My issue is about adding different items to customer's invoice. When you make an order, everything is ok until you press Finalize Order. Then, when you click on "see invoice", or check from Admin/Orders , everything is mixed up ...

Comment: Hi Nikos.. I am confused with your reply. What you mean exactly ..? What is mixed up in your invoice or order in admin section ..?

Comment: send me your email at zanikos@yahoo.com and I will send you an invoice from one of my orders.

Comment: I am sorry Nikos.. I am at office. Here I cant login my personal email(blocked). And I cant use my official email for this..Can you share your screen shot or can you share your invoice order(pdf) in some where and give me that link. I am sorry about that..

Comment: I deleted past orders with an extension, also I deleted items with magmi or from admin ( few weeks ago). Now, when I make an order, on invoice I find instead my name and address, a name and address from the deleted orders, and I find the item I bought but, also I find another 3 products. I guess, the solve of this issue is how to complety delete items and orders (it's like thoese deleted products and orders remained in a cache somewhere) ... hope you understood ...

Comment: Its unbelievable.. You said that you cleared all your cache, previous orders, products, and your name also. check your checkout process. You or others might be hard coded some where like or some thing. It can be fixed only digging the code and site directly. Sorry I am not able to answer for this question with these information.

Comment: Fixed for the moment ... I deleted all items, including categories. Seems to work now. Thanks for your help!